# Create Formula inside array after filter app script google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, binance, binance-api-client

I try to create formula inside array after filter this array, my array sometime don't give me price and sometime don't give me total price:
I need if the Price in array has 0.0 I want to change this to TotalPrice/Qty like first array 600/20=30 , The price is 30. and in second array
This is my code : TotalPrice is 0.0 do Qty*Price=TotalPrice : 10*20=200 , thee TotalPrice is 200 .

I need output like that:

```
[{Qty:20, Price:30, TotalPrice:600}, {Qty:10, Price:20, TotalPrice:200}, 
     {Qty:5, Price:100, TotalPrice:500}]
```

And then I put it to sheet by this code:

```
sh.getRange(5,5,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
```

Thanks.

```
function arrayFormula() {
   const data = '[{"Qty":"20", "Price":"0.0", "TotalPrice":"600"}, {"Qty":"10", "Price":"20", 
     "TotalPrice":"0.0"}, {"Qty":"5", "Price":"100", "TotalPrice":"500"}]';
   
   Logger.log("Array: "+ data);
   const obj = JSON.parse(data);
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   const oA = obj.map(obj => [obj.Qty, obj.Price,obj.TotalPrice]);

   // put array return to sheet
   //sh.getRange(5,5,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);


  var filtered = oA.filter(function (el) {
     if (el[1]!=0) {
       return obj.Total/obj.Qty; 
     } else {
       return false 
     }
  });

 console.log("Array After Filter: " + filtered);

 }
```

Return me :

```
1:16:27 PM  Info    Array: [{"Qty":"20", "Price":"0.0", "Total":"600"}, {"Qty":"10", 
                           "Price":"20", "Total":"0.0"}, {"Qty":"5", "Price":"100", 
                           "Total":"500"}]
1:16:27 PM  Info    Array After Filter:
```

Like this photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgcq7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
function main() {
  const data = `[
    {"Qty":"20", "Price":"0.0", "TotalPrice":"600"}, 
    {"Qty":"10", "Price":"20", "TotalPrice":"0.0"}, 
    {"Qty":"5", "Price":"100", "TotalPrice":"500"}
  ]`;
  const obj = JSON.parse(data);

  const calc_price = obj => 
    obj.Price == 0 ? obj.TotalPrice / obj.Qty : obj.Price;

  const calc_total_price = obj => 
    obj.TotalPrice == 0 ? obj.Price * obj.Qty : obj.TotalPrice;

  const oA = obj.map(o => [o.Qty, calc_price(o), calc_total_price(o)]);

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(5,5,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You give me number from last array `{"Qty":"5", "Price":"100", "TotalPrice":"500"}` , I need output like that `[{Qty:20, Price:30, TotalPrice:600}, {Qty:10, Price:20, TotalPrice:200}, {Qty:5, Price:100, TotalPrice:500}]` and then I put it to sheet by this code `sh.getRange(5,5,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);` .this is what I need thanks for reply

Comment: Okay. I've updated (changed actually) my answer.